# Differential amplifier - transfer characteristic question

Tags: amplifier, differential

I have a question regarding differential amplifier's transfer characteristic.

If we have a circuit like this (note that \$V_{1}=-V_{2}\$, hence \$V_{cm}=0V\$):

[image]

the transfer characteristic for \$V_{out1}\$ and \$V_{out2}\$ looks like this:

[image]

Where \$k_x=-\frac{R_C}{2R_E}\$

But if \$V_1\$ stays the same and we connect T2's base (i.e. \$V_2\$) to the ground, then the transfer characteristic is:

[image]

Where \$k_x'=-\frac{R_C}{R_E}\$

And I can't figure out how this happens. In other words: how should I analyze the circuit to determine its output characteristic(s).

I think this might be helpful:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that the last circuit is a **small signal equivalent circuit**, you can only use for **small deviations** around a chosen (biasing) point of the **large signal** transfer curves (the plots with red and green). So that circuit can be helpful but it is a linearized model of the original circuit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you are mystified. Your question isn't about the case when both BJTs are in their active region (which is a VERY TINY part of your curves.) It's about what happens when one of the BJTs is ***off*** and the other one is ***saturated***. You don't need any *small signal analysis* to get you through that problem. It's just trivial, now.

Let's look at your first case, slightly modified:

[image]

Here, you can see a tiny ***green*** band where both BJTs are in their active range. This will be approximately when their base voltages are about \$\pm30\:\text{mV}\$, or their difference is \$\le 60\:\text{mV}\$.

If you recall, \$60\:\text{mV}\$ accounts for about a factor of 10X change in collector current. At \$0\:\text{mV}\$ difference, the currents should be balanced and equal to each other (identical BJTs.) So with about \$60\:\text{mV}\$ difference between them there should be about 91% of the collector current on one side and 9% collector current on the other side. So that's about as far as it goes with both BJTs in active mode. This is the ***green*** band region.

In this green region, you should see:

$$I_1-I_2=I_0\frac{e^\frac{V_1}{V_T}-e^\frac{V_2}{V_T}}{e^\frac{V_1}{V_T}+e^\frac{V_2}{V_T}}$$

Where \$I_0\$ is the current in \$R_1\$ (making an assumption that this current is fairly constant) and \$V_1\$ is the base voltage for \$Q_1\$ and similarly \$V_2\$ is the base voltage for \$Q_2\$.

The green region covers the case where both BJTs are in their active region.

The orange region is where one of the BJTs is still ***active*** while the other one is basically ***off***. Outside the orange region, one BJT is entirely ***off*** and the other one is entirely ***on*** (and saturated.)

If you ground one of the BJT bases, then this only means that the collector will be ***very*** close to its emitter. And since the emitter is about one \$V_\text{BE}\$ below the base (which is at ground, by definition), the collector will exhibit a flat line outside the green region, instead.

That's really all there is to it.